# addMarkers function in leaflet not allowing to filter data

Tags: r, leaflet, shiny

I am using the leaflet library in shinyapps. I am trying to show markers which I have saved as icons depending on a user input dropdown choice. In the example below, I am unable to filter out the markers based on the user input. Similar code works when I run using only leaflet package without shiny.

The sample code below is in server.r in Shiny.

```
filteredData <- reactive({
    sampling_data[sampling_data$county == input$county_select, ]
    })

  theData <- filteredData()
    leafletProxy("mapData") %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%
      addMarkers(lng = sampling_data$lon,
                 lat = sampling_data$lat,
                 clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
  })

  output$mapData <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(sampling_data) %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldTopoMap) %>%
      setView(lng = -75, lat = 43, zoom = 6)
  })
  observe({
    theData <- filteredData()
    leafletProxy("mapData") %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%
      addMarkers(lng = sampling_data$lon,
                 lat = sampling_data$lat,
                 clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
  })
```

This code, without shiny, works fine

```
  subsetData <- sampling_data %>%
  filter(county == "Albany")

  leaflet(subsetData) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(lng = ~lon,
             lat = ~lat)
```

Comment: Can you please share the code with addCirceMarkers that works fine?

Comment: Hi @Seymour. I made an error in posing the question. I meant to say that the code works without shiny just using leaflet. However, it breaks when running leaflet under shiny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need the `leafletProxy` to appear in your `observe` block.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(

  mainPanel(
    leafletOutput("map"),
    sliderInput("depth", "Depth",
                min = min(quakes$depth),
                max = max(quakes$depth),
                value = c(min(quakes$depth), max(quakes$depth))
    ),
    textOutput("value")
  )

)

server <- function(input, output) {

  filteredData <- reactive({

    quakes %>%
      filter(depth >= input$depth[1] & depth <= input$depth[2])

  })

  output$value <- renderText({paste("min: ", input$depth[1], " max: ", input$depth[2])})

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({

    leaflet(quakes) %>%
      fitBounds(~min(long),
                ~min(lat),
                ~max(long),
                ~max(lat))

  })

  observe({

    leafletProxy("map") %>%
      clearTiles %>%
      clearMarkers %>%
      addTiles %>%
      addMarkers(lng = filteredData()$long, lat = filteredData()$lat)

  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```